# MySQL or Postgres: linked server equivalents

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, postgresql, linked-tables

In MSSQL exists the `linked server` concept, where you connect an external DB and link some tables of it in your current DB engine.
For my application I want to do the opposite, have an interface to MSSQL from Postgres or MySQL. Is there an equivalent to linked servers?

Comment: In Postgres that would be done through a [foreign data wrapper](https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw). See e.g. here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3663/sql-server-and-postgresql-foreign-data-wrapper-configuration--part-3/

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL you might wanna look into Foreign Data Wrappers, e.g. [`mysql-fdw`](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/08/24/postgresql-accessing-mysql-as-a-data-source-using-mysql_fdw/), [`oracle_fdw`](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw) (developed by a fellow SO user). For MSSQL check also the [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3663/sql-server-and-postgresql-foreign-data-wrapper-configuration--part-3/) posted by @a_horse_with_no_name in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB, the MySQL fork maintained by the original MySQL team, offers the [CONNECT storage engine with a JDBC connection type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-jdbc-table-type-accessing-tables-from-another-dbms/).

It's not trivial to rig up. It probably won't be available on shared servers at hosting companies.  It does access to data on multiple table server makes and models.